# Google Apps Script API - Permissions for my Python script to execute an Apps Script function

Tags: python, google-apps-script, google-cloud-platform, oauth-2.0, google-apps-script-api

this is my first contribution here.

I'm trying to access Gmail through a python script. To do so, I've created a Google Apps Script function and used the Apps Script API between the 2.
([This doc](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/how-tos/execute) displays what I'm trying to do)

So the [python script correctly accesses the API, but fails to execute the function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T7LCt.png).
While it works in the Script Editor, in Python it raises a permissions issue:

```
'errorMessage': 'Exception: The script does not have permission to perform that action.
Required permissions: (
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.labels ||
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.metadata ||
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly ||
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.modify ||
https://mail.google.com/
)',
'errorType': 'ScriptError'
```

I guess it is related to the Client ID OAuth, since I was not able to find where to grant it permissions. I've just :

- created the credentials in Google Cloud Platform,
- exported it as creds.json in my python script folder.

Here is my code, almost copy pasted from a tutorial:

```
import pickle
import os.path
from googleapiclient import errors
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from google.auth.transport.requests import Request

# Here I've edited the scopes of authorizations required
SCOPES = [
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.labels",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.metadata",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.modify",
    "https://mail.google.com/"
  ]
    
def get_scripts_service():
    creds = None
    # The file token.pickle stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
    # created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
    # time.
    if os.path.exists('token.pickle'):
        with open('token.pickle', 'rb') as token:
            creds = pickle.load(token)
    if not creds or not creds.valid:
        if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
            creds.refresh(Request())
        else:
            # Here I've placed the downloaded credentials .json file
            flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
                'creds.json', SCOPES)  
            creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
        with open('token.pickle', 'wb') as token:
            pickle.dump(creds, token)

    return build('script', 'v1', credentials=creds)


service = get_scripts_service()

API_ID = # Here i've pasted my API_ID

request = {"function": # Here i've pasted my functionName} 

try:
    response = service.scripts().run(body=request, scriptId=API_ID).execute()

    print (response)
except errors.HttpError as error:
    # The API encountered a problem.
    print(error.content)
```

How do I grant permissions to my script?

Comment: have you deleted the token after modifying the scopes?

Answer (score 1):

Simple as Aerials said! Thanks.
It was because the Client ID was created before I edited the scopes. I've deleted the token and created a new one.